# Python username and password login while and for loop

Tags: csv, for-loop, authentication, while-loop, python-3.4

I have a school assignment to make a program with a login for a hospital (we have to make a eHealth system). But the problem with my code is that it checks every .csv line only once. Whenever my first login is wrong it stops looping and I can't login anymore. Also it checks every single line and prints the one's that are wrong. How can I fix my code so that I can still login after filling in a wrong login?

```
import csv


def login():
    print('Welcome to the eHealth program, please sign in')

    with open('users.csv') as csvfile:
        database = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        loggedin = False
        while loggedin is not True:
            Username = input('Fill in your username: ')
            Password = input('Fill in your password: ')
            for row in database:
                Username_File = row['username']
                Password_File = row['password']
                Function_File = row['function']
                if (Username_File == Username and
                    Password_File == Password and
                        Function_File == 'patient'):
                    loggedin = True
                    print('Succesfully logged in as a patient.')
                    # patientmenu()  # we will add this later on
                elif (Username_File == Username and
                      Password_File == Password and
                        Function_File == 'arts'):
                    loggedin = True
                    print('Succesfully logged in as a doctor.')
                    # artsmenu()     # we will add this later on
                elif Username_File != Username and Password_File == Password:
                    # loggedin = False
                    print('Failed to sign in, wrong username.')
                elif Username_File == Username and Password_File != Password:
                    # loggedin = False
                    print('Failed to sign in, wrong password.')
                elif Username_File != Username and Password_File != Password:
                    # loggedin = False
                    print('Failed to sign in, wrong username and password.')
               else:
                    print('Error 404, Login Not Found')

# ---- Main ---- #
login()
```

example of thats in the csv file: (doesn't really matter for this case)

```
username,password,function
patient1,patient1,patient
patient2,patient2,patient
arts1,arts1,arts
arts2,arts2,arts
```

I've tried fixing it by putting the with open into the while loop, but another problem occurs then. Now it prints 4 lines every single time, if you are correctly logged in it prints 1 line with successfully logged in and 3 lines with wrong username and password.

```
import csv

def login():
    print('Welcome to the eHealth program, please sign in')

    loggedin = False
    while loggedin != True:
        Username = input('Fill in your username: ')
        Password = input('Fill in your password: ')
        with open ('users.csv') as csvfile:
            database = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in database:
                Username_File = row['username']
                print(Username_File)
                Password_File = row['password']
                print(Password_File)
                Function_File = row['function']
                print(Function_File)
                if Username_File == Username and Password_File == Password and Function_File == 'patient':
                    loggedin = True
                    print('Succesfully logged in as a patient.')
                elif Username_File == Username and Password_File == Password and Function_File == 'arts':
                    loggedin = True
                    print('Succesfully logged in as a doctor.')
                elif Username_File != Username and Password_File == Password:
                    loggedin = False
                    print('Failed to sign in, wrong username.')
                elif Username_File == Username and Password_File != Password:
                    loggedin = False
                    print('Failed to sign in, wrong password.')
                elif Username_File != Username and Password_File != Password:
                    loggedin = False
                    print('Failed to sign in, wrong username and password.')
                else:
                    print('Error 404, Login Not Found')

login()
```

Comment: Why is the `while` loop underneath the `with open(...) as` block? All you need there is the `database = ...` line. Once you have read in the contents of the file you don't need it open any more. I would unindent everything else by one to take it out of that block

Comment: @KenB I don't understand could you maybe show it to me in python-code? There reason why I used a while loop is because whenever you filled in a wrong username and password you need to restart the program.

Comment: Are you on python 3.x or 2.7?

Comment: @DamienBrils what I mean is this: the `with open('users.csv') as csvfile:` statement opens the file `users.csv`, then closes it when all the code under it is done. But you only need to leave it open long enough to read its contents into your `database` variable. So I would move the `while` loop out from under the `with... as` block, like this: https://gist.github.com/kenbellows/c0f7d4f444e9aa359388

Comment: @KenB The way it is executed above, that is not true. `database` is a `csv.DictReader` instance that needs the csv file to be open to perform operations on it.

DamienBrils Under python3, your code fails for me at `Password_File = row['password']`, does it run for you?

Comment: @sobek ah good point, made a bad assumption there; ignore my prior comments

Comment: @sobek it does run for me in python 3.4.3

Comment: That's because you probably don't have spaces in your csv file *sigh*. I can now reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DamienBrils See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what's happening:

Your while loop stays active, but after you have looped over all rows in your csv file, you don't enter the for loop any more because there's no rows left to loop over. If you want to fix it, you need to find a way to reset the for loop once you have processed the last row.

As suggested by Roberto Alcantara in his answer, a more elegant solution would be to construct 3 datasets with all the usernames, passwords and functions before you even enter your while loop, then you can just check along the lines of:

```
if username in usernames:
    do some stuff
else:
    do some other stuff
```

and that would allow you to do that in the while loop without having to iterate over the csv reader instance all the time.

I've also taken the liberty of fixing some formatting stuff that was not really pythonic in your code (though not really wrong).

---

### Edit:

Here's something i quickly cobbled together, it's not as nice a i intended it to be because it does once again loop over the content of the created database, but at least it works:

```
import csv


def login():
    print('Welcome to the eHealth program, please sign in')

    with open('users.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        database = []
        for row in reader:
            database.append(dict(username=row['username'],
                                 password=row['password'],
                                 function=row['function']))

    loggedin = False
    while not loggedin:
        Username = input('Fill in your username: ')
        Password = input('Fill in your password: ')
        for row in database:
            Username_File = row['username']
            Password_File = row['password']
            Function_File = row['function']
            if (Username_File == Username and
                Password_File == Password and
                    Function_File == 'patient'):
                loggedin = True
                print('Succesfully logged in as a patient.')
            elif (Username_File == Username and
                  Password_File == Password and
                    Function_File == 'arts'):
                loggedin = True
                print('Succesfully logged in as a doctor.')
        if loggedin is not True:
            print ('Failed to sign in, wrong username or password.')

# ---- Main ---- #
login()
```

I'm sure some python wizard around here could come up with a solution to cleverly use datatypes so you can still link usernames, passwords and roles without having to loop, but it gets the job done.

Another thing i'd like to suggest:

As you've probably seen, i have removed the prints that indicated whether a password was found, but the username was wrong and vice versa. It greatly compromises security to hint at whether a username or password scored a hit in your database even though the login as such was unsuccessful, so unless your assignment specifically asks for it, i would leave that be. On the otherhand, talking security is kind of moot when you store passwords in plaintext. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to build a database feeding a dictionary on program start with cvs content.

After that you can create your loop to check this dictionary and apply your logic on it.

This link maybe can help you to understand python dictionary: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm